# Media query not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

Media query is not working when I resize my window, `(max-width: 768px)` is
working and `(max-width:425px)` is not working but and when I inspect
my page, both are not working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 50px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        span {
            font-size: 40px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: rgba(68, 77, 78, 0.6);
        }

        .box {
            position: relative;
            width: 25%;
            float: left;
        }

        .img-text {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .project-image {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        /* this is working when resize window but not when I inspect my page */

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .box {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        /* this is not working on both */

        @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
            .box {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="project">
        <h2>Project</h2>
        <div class="project-img-container">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Summer House</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house5.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Brick House</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house2.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Renovated</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house3.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Barn House</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house4.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Summer House</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house2.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Brick House</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house5.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Renovated</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house4.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <span class="img-text">Barn House</span>
                <img class="project-image" src="house3.jpg" alt="#">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Why does my code output is different on both inspect window and live server?

Comment: I would like to help, what are the dimensions of the images? width and height

Comment: Image dimension:-  500 x 333px

Comment: I didn't really understand your problem very well. But you might need to add `width: 50%` to `(max-width: 425px)` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you’re having trouble with Mobile Optimization, it looks like you need to add the following meta tag to your html.

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```